# PHP Login and session

Tags: php, session, authentication

Good morning/evening,

I'm stuck and I need some help in PHP.

I am trying to code up an admin dashboard. And I want to check if user is logged in, if not , redirect to the login page.

My index.php is this:

```
<?php
$pagename ="Index";

@require_once('inc/head.php');
?>
<body>
CONGRATS! Welcome to the Admin dashboard.
</body>
</html>
```

My login page:

```
<?php
$pagename = "login";
$adminUser = "admin";
$adminPass = "admin";

@require_once('inc/head.php');

// If POST is submitted and IDs match the ones set
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if($_POST["username"] == $adminUser && $_POST["password"] == $adminPass)

    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["username"] = $adminUser;
    $_SESSION["login"] = true;
    echo '<script>alert("Congrats, you logged in");
    window.location = "index.php"; </script>';

 /* I skip the line underneath because for unknown reasons my code 
  Doesn't fully run through. So I redirected with the JS above instead.

  header("Location: index.php");
    exit(); */
    }else{
    echo '<script>alert("Incorrect username or password!'");</script>';
    }   
}
?>

<html>
<!-- login page here -->
</html>
```

And here goes my head.php:

```
<?php

  // If we AREN'T on the login page , check if session exist. If not send to login
if($pagename != "login")
{       if(!$_SESSION['login'])
     {
        header('location: login.php');  
        exit();
     }
}
?>
```

There is alot of things wrong with this and I know but as of now I'm trying to fix my login in issue. Whenever I log in I get the JS pop up that says I successfully logged in, but I don't get redirected to the index. I think I do get sent to my index.php ( there's no reason for my JS redirect to NOT function ) but my index sends me right back to login and I don't understand why.

Comment: was the session started in all pages using them? Doesn't seem to be the case for the head.php file.

Comment: `session_start();` missing in **head.php**

Comment: But I only want to create a session after the user logs in.. Or do I need to create one regardless and THEN add value to it when the user logs in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start Session in **head.php** page.

**head.php**

```
<?php
if($pagename != "login") {
  session_start();
  if(!$_SESSION['login']) {
    header('location: login.php');  
    exit();
  }
}
?>
```