# How to check session on page in php?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have created the session on the login page and stored in a variable.
on the Login page

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
```

Now I want to check session that exists or not? 
       On other pages

```
  <?php 
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
     echo 'Session is active';
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Login and session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916752/php-login-and-session)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
session_start();
```

on top of file to start the session.

To set a value,

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;
```

To check if session exists and not empty

```
if(!empty($_SESSION))
{
    // write code here
}
```

To check for a particular value is set

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    // write code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use isset

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
   echo 'Session is active';   
}
```